# wxBitmap depth on mac causes slow drawing

Tags: c++, macos, drawing, wxwidgets

Under a 24 bit colour depth display (like my MacBookPro13,3 with Radeon Pro 460 24-Bit Colour (ARGB8888)), I am finding drawing wxBitmap on to a DC to be very slow.
I am using wxWidgets 3.1.2 using a wxAutoBufferedPaintDC and am simply calling dc.DrawBitmap(myBitmap, sizeX, sizeY, true);

Profiling under Instruments, I see the following output:

```
6.56 s   56.3%  2.00 ms      myThing::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s           wxGCDCImpl::DoDrawBitmap(wxBitmap const&, int, int, bool)
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s            wxMacCoreGraphicsContext::DrawBitmap(wxBitmap const&, double, double, double, double)
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s             wxOSXDrawNSImage(CGContext*, CGRect const*, NSImage*)
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s              -[NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:]
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s               -[NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:]
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                -[NSImage _usingBestRepresentationForRect:context:hints:body:]
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                 __71-[NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:]_block_invoke.1317
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                  -[NSImageRep drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:]
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                   __74-[NSImageRep drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:]_block_invoke
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                    CGContextDrawImage
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                     CGContextDrawImageWithOptions
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                      CGContextDelegateDrawImage
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                       backing_store_DrawImage.llvm.1028279097235270472
5.83 s   50.0%  0 s                        backing_store_delegate
5.83 s   49.9%  0 s                         __backing_store_DrawImage_block_invoke
5.83 s   49.9%  0 s                          CGContextDelegateDrawImage
5.83 s   49.9%  0 s                           ripc_DrawImage
5.82 s   49.9%  0 s                            ripc_RenderImage
5.82 s   49.9%  0 s                             RIPLayerBltImage
5.82 s   49.9%  0 s                              ripl_Mark
5.82 s   49.9%  0 s                               RGBAf16_image
5.82 s   49.9%  778.00 ms                                RGBAf16_image_mark(BltDepth const*, BltOp const*, _ImgOp*, MODE)
5.04 s   43.2%  5.04 s                                  RGBAf16_sample_RGBAf_inner(_ImgOp const*, long, long, int)
```

Looking through the code in src/osx/core/bitmap.cpp, it seems that the wxBitmap under macOS is always 32 bits. This seems to be forcing the pixel data to be slowly transformed instead of just doing a memcpy to the target, I guess???

Drawing this bitmap under my 32bit display on my aging 2012 MacBookPro9,1 running Sierra (thought it was High Sierra but obviously not!) I am not experiencing any speed issues at all and it's super speedy.

What can I do to ***really*** create a wxBitmap under the system's native display depth in macOS?

I have asked this question on the wxWidgets forum but thought I'd ask here too for reaching a potentially wider audience.

EDIT: Note! Following advice on the wxWidgets forum, I have opened this as a bug https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/18516 but would welcome any suggestions here in the meantime.

Comment: Traces available as referenced in the bug report/forum posts.